# SCOM isn't recording Performance Counters for SQL

Tags: sql, scom

I am working on a installation of SCOM, monitoring some SQL Servers. However, I am having an issue collecting the performance counters.

In particular, in SCOM it is showing that the Page Life Expectancy is 0 for all of my SQL Server, when in fact is above 20,000 on most of the servers.

I can't see anything in the SCOM Logs to suggest why this is happening. Any suggestions as to the possible cause, or places to look for more information will be greatly appreciated.

James

Answer (score 0):

I'm a team member of the SQL Server Management Pack development team. Thank you so much for this feedback. We'll need slightly more details from you to research this issue. Right now we are collecting all issues via MS Connect portal. Could you, please post this issue via https://connect.microsoft.com/WindowsServer/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx

There is a link "Bug Form for System Center Operations Manager". When you post your issue there - it will come directly to our support team. We'll need the following details:

- SCOM version
- SQL MP version
- SQL Server version
- Some screenshots if possible

Thank you,
Roman.